# In Lua, how can I check if a buffer exists on disk?

Tags: neovim, lua

I use Neotree on Neovim, and have mapped a key to open the file browser which is supposed to:

- open the file browser pointing to the current file
- if there is no filename, open the file browser at the current working dir.

It works well *except* in the case that the buffer has a filename, but that file does not exist, e.g. if you start nvim with the name of a file you intend to create but have not yet saved.

Here's my existing code:

```lua
local d = vim.fn.getreg('%')                                 
if (d == '') then d = vim.fn.getcwd(); end                                                          
vim.cmd("Neotree reveal_force_cwd " .. vim.fn.fnameescape(d))
```

In the failing case the `%` reg is not empty, but it has no file associated with it.

Is there a vim built-in that knows this? or a way to check for the existence of the file?

Comment: I think the Vim function is `filereadable()`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```lua
local d = vim.fn.getreg('%')                                 
if (d == '') then                                            
  d = vim.fn.getcwd();                                       
else                                                         
  local f = io.open(d, "r") -- Attempt to open the file
  if (f) then     
    f.close(f)              -- Close file if we opened it ok
  else
    d = vim.fn.getcwd()     -- Could not open file, use cwd
  end                                                        
end                                                          
vim.cmd("Neotree reveal_force_cwd " .. vim.fn.fnameescape(d))
```